# how to get file size in javascript or jquery with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

how to get file size in javascript or jquery with rails here by word size i means to say content size of file like 100kb.

here i got some methods like size or file size but its not working for me

my ruby code is

```
<%= upload_form.file_field  :upload_file_name1,:onchange =>"return         validateFileExtension(this)"%>




 function validateFileExtension(fld) {
alert(fld.value.fileSize);
  if(!/(\.jpg|\.gif|\.png)$/i.test(fld.value)) {
    alert("Invalid file type! Kindly upload in a JPG, GIF or PNG format!");
    fld.parentNode.innerHTML = fld.parentNode.innerHTML;
    fld.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You need to **accept** some questions.

Comment: Or if there are numerous answers to your questions you obviously choose (accept) the one that was most suitable or you found most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function A()
{
var oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var d = document.a.b.value;
var e = oas.getFile(d);
var f = e.size;
alert(f + " bytes");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="a">
<input type="file" name="b">
<input type="button" name="c" value="SIZE" onClick="A();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```